# Separate by loose parts, but the results are all faces

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am using separate by loose parts command on one of my quite complex model, but after separation all the parts just became individual faces and there are thousands of them. I really don't want edit faces one by one, are there any good alternatives to actually split objects into objects instead of faces?

Comment: Separate by loose parts should only separate groups of vertices that are disconnected from other groups of vertices - it shouldn't do it for every face unless they are disconnected from each other (result of an edge-split, maybe?). Regardless, you could perhaps try doing a _merge by distance_ operation before separating and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Same thing happening for me in 2.93. Really wonky. Worked fine all the time. Workaround for me was to separate a few groups by material from there I can then further break these groups down with separate by loose parts.